# did cobalt RC_9 implement webGL?

Tags: cobalt

in WebGL performance Tests of qual-e,  video["webkitDecodedFrameCount"] is undefined.
did cobalt RC_9 implement webGL on latest GIT version ?

if cobalt support webGL, could you tell us how to test it?

Answer (score 2):

No, Cobalt does not support WebGL. For 360 video, Cobalt supports the map-to-mesh CSS extension instead.

See here for info on how to support 360 video:
https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/src/cobalt/doc/spherical_video.md

Comment: Indeed...  See here for how to implement support for 360 video using Cobalt: https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/src/cobalt/doc/spherical_video.md